# Отсутствует "<<" оператор, соответствующий этим операндам C++

Tags: c++

Знаю, что что-то делаю неправильно, нуждаюсь в помощи. Имеется структура типа Classmates_Info в ней два вектора типа string, при попытке вывести значения с помощью цикла, ничего не получается, что надумал не так? Компилятор VS 2015.

```
for(vector<Classmates_Info>::const_iterator iter = Class.begin(); iter != Class.end(); ++iter){  
cout << (*iter).names << setw(maxlenNam) << (*iter).surnames << endl;  
}

struct Classmates_Info{
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::vector<std::string> surnames;
};
```

Comment: код структуры привидите.

Comment: а вектор разве напрямую можно пхать в cout?

Comment: Ну так я и спрашиваю, как тогда сделать?

Comment: очевидно так же как и для вектора с `Classmates_Info`, почему для одного вектора используете `for` а другие пытаетесь напрямую?

Comment: @StirolCraft писать код `ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const vector<std::string> &names)`

Comment: @Grundy Я использую оператор разыменования, чтобы с помощью итератора вывести имена и фамилии так сказать, из контейнера типа Classmates_Info. Про какие другие векторы вы говорите? Которые в структуре?

Comment: @StirolCraft да, конечно. Оператор << - не определен ни для каких векторов. А лучше сразу написать `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Classmates_Info &info)`

Comment: я вот про этот: `for(vector<Classmates_Info>`

Comment: А как объяснить конкретно, как я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка вот тут:

```
cout << (*iter).names <<...
```

Напишите это вот так (получится то же самое)

```
for (...) { // самый внешний цикл
   vector<string> names = (*iter).names;
   cout << names; // выдаст ту же ошибку
}
```

Нужно как-то так:

```
for (...) { // внешний цикл
   for (string name: (*iter).names) {
       cout << name << ' ';
   }
   cout << endl;
   for (string name: (*iter).surnames) {
       cout << name << ' ';
   }
}
```

А лучше написать определение оператора

```
ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const Classmates_Info &info) {
   // форматируйте как Вам удобно
       for (string name: info.names) {
           cout << name << ' ';
       }
       cout << endl;
       for (string name: info.surnames) {
           cout << name << ' ';
       }
}
```

и когда нужно вывести вектор объектов `Classmates_Info`

```
for (const auto &info: vector<Classmates_Info>) { // Приблизительно эквивалентно Вашему for
   cout << info << endl;
}
```

Comment: А почему тогда автор книги мне не говорит, что надо так использовать или я что-то недопонимаю, вот пример https://pp.vk.me/c636126/v636126597/160bb/1uTPOMifnjc.jpg, но ни один у меня так и не получилось скомпилировать, почему?

Comment: @StirolCraft Подозреваю, что у автора книги структура `Student_info` описывает *ОДНОГО* студента и `Student_info::name` имеет тип `std::string`, а вовсе не `std::vector<std::string>`