# Ошибка 0349 отсутствует оператор, соответствующий этим операндам

Tags: c++, ооп

Пишу программу на С++, в которой надо разработать определения двух классов COne и CTwo, которые связаны отношением включения. Проблема возникает в мейне, при попытке вывести `A.getObj()`.

Сама ошибка : **0349    отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операндам**

Скорее всего ошибка возникает из-за того, что в классе отсутствует нужный метод. Помогите с его реализацией, пожалуйста

```
//MAIN
#include <iostream>
#include <String.h>
#include "CTwo.h"
#include "COne.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    CTwo A("CTwo String","COne String", 505);
    A.Print();

    
    cout << A.getS() <<  endl;
    cout << A.getObj() << endl; // <==== ошибка тут


}


//COne.h
#ifndef CONE_H
#define CONE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class COne
{

    protected:
        string s;
        double d;
        
    public:
        COne();
        COne(string S, double D);
        ~COne();

        COne(const COne& arg);
        
        void print();

        COne(COne& arg);

        const double& getD();
        const string& getS();

        void Print();

        COne& operator=(const COne& arg);

        friend class CTwo;
};
#endif


//CTwo.h
#ifndef CTWO_H
#define CTWO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "COne.h"

using namespace std;
class COne;

class CTwo
{
protected:
    string s;
    COne obj;

public:
    CTwo();
    CTwo(string S, string SOne, double d);
    virtual ~CTwo();
    void Print();

    const string& getS();
    const COne& getObj();


    friend class COne;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с понятием [mcve] и приведите к нему код.

Comment: Попробуйте взглянуть [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795780/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be?rq=1) и [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545094/Отсутствует-оператор-соответствующий-этим-операндам-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

добавьте функцию вида, можно даже возле `int main()`

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& os, const COne& one)
{
  os << one.getD() << " / " << one.getS();
  return os; // эта строка обязательна
};
```

возможно, нужно будет добавить `#include <ostream>`